# Proving Mallows Cp is an unbiased estimator of test MSE

Tags: self-study, unbiased-estimator, mse

In the book Introduction to Statistical Learning , Cp is introduced as a statistic to chose an optimal model for a linear regression setting(Page 211), Cp which is given by

[image]

it is given that if [image] is the unbiased estimator of [image](ie. the variance of irreducible error) then it is given that the above [image] statistic is an unbiased estimate for test MSE.

So my questions are,

1.What exactly is the test MSE here? Is it the Expected Prediction error?
that is given by

[image]

**1.a.If the first answer is yes** , then how do I go about proving it is an unbiased estimator?

This is what I have tried assuming the first answer is yes,
I considered the case of simple linear regression so that d=2 in the formula and finding its expected value ie.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then the equation for Expected Prediction Error

As model assumption is unbiased, the Bias term goes to zero and we get

[image]

I am not sure how to deal with the Var(f(x)) term , heres where I am stuck
any help would be appreciated.

***2*.If first answer is a no** , then what is the test MSE authors are talking about?

Comment: In statistics, MSE means mean square error. If I were you, I would try to find the explicit definition of test MSE in that book. If could not find, the book would go to garbage can and I would try to find another good book.

Comment: Yes, that would be a great idea .

Comment: Eq. (2.28) in book `Elements of Statistical Learning` maybe helpful? @Fenil https://hastie.su.domains/ElemStatLearn/